# Why is the CheckBox Content color not changing?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I'm using [MahApps.Metro](https://mahapps.com/) for my WPF app. As shown in the image below, the `Forground` color of a `CheckBox` remains default (black) if I try to change it to white.

**Question**: How can we change the content color to white?

**None of the following XAMLs change the content's forground color. It remains default (black)**:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="chkTest" Content="Test Content" FontSize="20" Foreground="{StaticResource MahApps.Brushes.Badged.Foreground}" />
```

**Or**:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="chkTest" Content="Set Default" FontSize="20" Foreground="White" />
```

**Or** -as discussed [here](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/3797):

```
<CheckBox x:Name="chkTest" Content="Test Content" FontSize="20" Foreground="{StaticResource MahApps.Brushes.CheckBox.ForegroundChecked}" />
```

**Display of the above XAMLs**:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *MahApps.Metro* `CheckBox` style has many states and triggers, which use different brushes. Overriding the `Forground` property does not cover all states.

However, there is a dedicated type `CheckBoxHelper` with many attached properties that you can use to customize every brush in each state for the content, as well as for the check mark glyph. Look for properties starting with `Foreground...` and `CheckGlyphForeground...`. There are attached properties for check mark and content background as well.

```
<CheckBox x:Name="chkTest" Content="Set Default" FontSize="20"
          mah:CheckBoxHelper.ForegroundUnchecked="Blue"
          mah:CheckBoxHelper.ForegroundUncheckedMouseOver="Green"
          mah:CheckBoxHelper.CheckGlyphForegroundChecked="Red"
          mah:CheckBoxHelper.CheckGlyphForegroundCheckedMouseOver="Purple"/>
```

Comment: Your suggestion worked. I used the following 4 to make the content stay white whether it's checked, unchecked or mouseover. Although I understand there is a reason for defining color for each state, but I wish there was a single property as well for just content's foreground color regardless of what state the control is in - so one wouldn't have to use 4 properties to make it work: `mah:CheckBoxHelper.ForegroundChecked="White" mah:CheckBoxHelper.ForegroundUnchecked="White" mah:CheckBoxHelper.ForegroundCheckedMouseOver="White" mah:CheckBoxHelper.ForegroundUncheckedMouseOver="White"`

Comment: I am trying to add a button or link to MahApps metro's ShowInputAsync(...) dialog box. The issue posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68537386/1232087) in - in case you have a time for a suggestion.